# Selecting Node for every time another node is repeated with XQuery with IMPORTXML on Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, xquery

So here's what I want to do. The following is the xml info (simplified) I get from an invoicing program. I would like to select the Invoicer Name for every time I have a different product. So in
my query I'd get:

```
Element='<invoicerName>Jack</invoicerName>'
Element='<invoicerName>Jack</invoicerName>'
Element='<invoicerName>Jack</invoicerName>'
```

Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<invoices>
    <invoice>
    <invoicerInfo>
        <invoicerName>Jack</invoicerName>
    </invoicerInfo>
    <invoiceDetails>
        <productDescription>Soda</productDescription>
        <productDescription>Popcorn</productDescription>
        <productDescription>Tickets</productDescription>
    </invoiceDetails>
    <invoice>
</invoices>
```

I've tried a slew of options but I don't get repeated invoicerName values.

Comment: Using only XPath ? No XQuery ?

Comment: XQuery, I'll update the post. It's to run with IMPORTXML on Google Sheets.

Comment: From `It's to run with IMPORTXML on Google Sheets.`, in your situation, do you have a publicly shared direct link of the XML data? If my understanding is correct, can you provide a sample URL for testing?

Comment: It seems easy enough with pure XPath 2.0 but I'm not sure of the capabilities of GoogleSheets `IMPORTXML`

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets `IMPORTXML` seems to support XPath 2.0 so you should be able to use:

```bash
for $invoice in //invoice
return
    for $p in distinct-values($invoice//productDescription)
    return
        $invoice//invoicerName
```

That'll generate a list of `invoicerName` nodes, one for each unique `productDescription` of a given `invoice`

Comment: Thanks! I tried the code in Free Online XPath Tester and it worked, but I can't get it to work on Google sheets. Should I wrap the code some way. I put it in a cell and then referenced it in a simple: =IMPORTXML($A$2,B4) but I get a Error Imported Xml content can not be parsed.

Comment: @LuisFlores It's difficult to say; does an other XPath like `//invoicerName` work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. //invoicerName works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If Google Sheets has support for `group by` you can also use

```
for $i in //invoice
let $name := $i//invoicerName
return
  for $p in $i//productDescription
  group by $p
  return $name
```

here is the query in action with extended test data
https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVSgfb